# How to write a query to allow null in minimum function

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

I need to write a query to get minimum values for a column from a table and if the value is null then I want to include that row. I wrote following query but it ignores the null values. How I can modify this query to include null values in the result?

```
select * from TABLE where COLUMN = (select min(COLUMN) from TABLE );
```

If the table is like below

```
 |ID  | VALUE | NAME
  101    1      John
  101    null   John
  102    1      Bill
  103    1      Tina
  103    null   Tina
  104    null   James
```

Result Should be

```
|ID  | VALUE | NAME
 101   1       John
 102   1       Bill
 103   1       Tina
 104   null    James
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `distinct on`:

```
with my_table(id, value, name) as (
values
    (101, 1,    'John'),
    (101, null, 'John'),
    (102, 1,    'Bill'),
    (103, 1,    'Tina'),
    (103, null, 'Tina'),
    (104, null, 'James')
)

select distinct on (id) *
from my_table
order by id, value

 id  | value | name  
-----+-------+-------
 101 |     1 | John
 102 |     1 | Bill
 103 |     1 | Tina
 104 |       | James
(4 rows)
```

`Distinct on` is a fantastic feature specific for Postgres. An alternative in other RDBMS may be:

```
select t.id, t.value, t.name
from my_table t
join (
    select id, min(value) as value
    from my_table
    group by id
) u on u.id = t.id and u.value is not distinct from t.value;
```

Note, you should use `is not distinct from` because `value` may be null.

Comment: This gives me only one row in the result. I want to include rows for the minimum value of that column as well as the row with null value for that column (if no row with minimum value exists). I tried group by but couldn't get it to work since I need to include my_column in the group by clause.

Comment: Thanks this is close. What should be done so that I can do select * from my_table. I have more than two columns if I include that in select clause I need to add it in the group by clause too which breaks the result.

Comment: Ok, in this case we have another option. See the answer once more.

Comment: yes this works. Thanks! One last question Do you know if a distinct on clause is allowed in h2? I need to  be able to run this query in h2 as well as postgres.

Comment: I don't think so, see the answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

SQL SERVER

```
  select DISTINCT j.ID,j.VALUE,j.NAME from  Table1 j
                join (
                    select id, MIN(VALUE) VALUE from Table1
                    group by id
                ) as t
                on t.ID = j.ID and (t.VALUE = j.VALUE or t.VALUE is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do an equals (`=`) for a `null` value, you have to check `is null` or so. So one simple solution is to default the `null` value to a number that would not otherwise be used:

```
select * from TABLE where coalesce(COLUMN, -9999) = (select min(coalesce(COLUMN,-9999)) from TABLE );
```

The `coalesce` function returns the first non-null value passed to it.

Comment: see my updated question. I am either getting all null rows or all rows with some minimum value but not both at the same time. I need rows with minimum values as well as rows with null value (if it doesn't have a minimum value)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solve your problem.

```
SELECT id,
   CASE WHEN MIN(
         CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0 THEN null
   ELSE MIN(value) END
FROM tableName
GROUP BY id
```

or using `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT id,
   CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(value, 0)) = 0 THEN null
   ELSE MIN(value) END
FROM tableName
GROUP BY id
```

I am on mobile phone now, so I cannot test.

Comment: see my updated question. I am either getting all null rows or all rows with some minimum value but not both at the same time. I need rows with minimum values as well as rows with null value (if it doesn't have a minimum value)

Comment: Thanks - it is not necessarily keeping the rows with minimum values in the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
with c as (
    select column as c
    from table
    order by column nulls first
    limit 1
)
select *
from table cross join c
where column = c or column is null
```

Comment: see my updated question. I am either getting all null rows or all rows with some minimum value but not both at the same time. I need rows with minimum values as well as rows with null value (if it doesn't have a minimum value)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to user `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.column asc nulls first
limit 1;
```

Alternatively, use `rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (order by col asc nulls first) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: see my updated question. I am either getting all null rows or all rows with some minimum value but not both at the same time. I need rows with minimum values as well as rows with null value (if it doesn't have a minimum value)